# Python - Assert a text field that should not exist in the page

Tags: python, selenium, testing, webdriver, assert

Hello I am new in using selenium webdriver and I am trying to create a test script using selenium webdriver in python and I am trying to check if a certain text field is not existing in the page.

Here is the code that I have created to check if the text field is blank or empty:

```
driver = self.driver
    # Get page by URL
    driver.get(self.base_url + "/userk/mission/")
    # Get page by URL
    driver.get(self.base_url + "/mission/update/123-456-789/")
    self.assertEqual(self.base_url + "/mission/update/123-456-789/", driver.current_url)
    driver.find_element_by_id("discussion-btn").click()
    # Check if text is not present
    self.assertEqual("", driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[5]/div"))
```

This is the error that I received when I run the test:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "acttemplate_layouts.py", line 37, in test_task_xml
    self.assertEqual("", driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[5]/div"))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 290, in find_element_by_xpath
    return self.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value=xpath)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 744, in find_element
    {'using': by, 'value': value})['value']
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 231, in execute
    response = self.command_executor.execute(driver_command, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/remote_connection.py", line 395, in execute
    return self._request(command_info[0], url, body=data)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/remote_connection.py", line 426, in _request
    resp = self._conn.getresponse()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 1051, in getresponse
    response.begin()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 415, in begin
    version, status, reason = self._read_status()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 379, in _read_status
    raise BadStatusLine(line)
BadStatusLine: ''
```

Using this test script gives me an error. Please help me with the correct syntax or method that I should use. Thanks in advance.

Comment: show us more code and the error stack please

Comment: Here's the complete error message and test case.

Answer (score 2):

Add .text behind driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[5]/div")

```
self.assertEqual("", driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[5]/div").text)
```